# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.BestPractices_dbo.WorkOrder1_Id"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть база данных SQL Server из нескольких таблиц 
При выполнении программы столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.BestPractices_dbo.WorkOrder1_Id"

из за чего возможна данная ошибка? Как можно решить данную проблему??

```
class WorkOrder1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Accepter { get; set; }
    public string Foreman { get; set; }
    public string myDate { get; set; }
    public BestPractice bestPractice { get; set; }

    public int? GuideAuto1Id { get; set; }
    public GuideAuto1 GuideAuto1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1> GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s { get; set; }
    public WorkOrder1()
    {
        GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1s = new List<GuideWorkTypeStandardHour1>();
    }
}

class BestPractice
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("WorkOrder1")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MalfunctionAccordingClient { get; set; }
    public string FaultAccordingResultsInspection { get; set; }
    public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
    public string RecommendationsClientFutureRepairs { get; set; }

    public WorkOrder1 WorkOrder1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Думается что, это может быть из-за того что сейчас внешним ключом  таблицы `WorkOrder1` является `GuideAuto1Id`. Тогда надо ещё что ли один внешний ключ определить в таблице `WorkOrder1` ???

Comment: вписываешь какую-то запись, в которой поле ссылающееся на WorkOrder1 в таблице BestPractice имеет значение, отсутствующее в списке значений WorkOrder1 в таблице BestPractice/

Comment: В свойство  `WorkOrder1` таблицы `BestPractice` ничего я не вписываю!!!!

Comment: но если это внешний ключ в таблице бестпрактис то значение должно быть. просто база не дублирует это значение, а подставляет вместо него ссылку на таблицу, где эти значения прописаны. а когда ты вписываешь запись, то значение должно быть в списке значений этого внешнего ключа (поля).
это называется констрейнт - жесткое правило. так делают для устранения дублирования значений и формируют структуру БД.

Answer (score 2):

Если есть таблица BEST_PRACTICE с полями:

```
ID       NAME      COMMENT
==============================
1        RULE1     Правило А    
2        RULE2     Правило Б    
3        RULE3     Правило С
```

Есть таблица Work_Order, где поле RULE_NAME прописано как Foreign_KEY в таблице BEST_PRACTICE и указывает на поле NAME

Work_Order

```
ID      CODE          RULE_NAME
==============================
1       code1.cpp     RULE2
2       code2.cpp     RULE2
3       code3.cpp     RULE1
```

То при добавлении записи в Work_Order вида 
(поле ID как IDENT)

```
insert into work_order (code, rule_name) values ('code4.cpp', 'RULE5')
```

возникнет такая ошибка, поскольку **RULE5** как значение ключа (внешнего) в таблице BEST_PRACTICE не прописано...
а если, например:

```
insert into work_order (code, rule_name) values ('code4.cpp', 'RULE2')
```

то ошибки не будет..